# In Ms-SQL Server to restore database via script as below I would like to parameterize the database name, path and file name in an SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

In Ms-SQL Server to restore database I have a script as below but would like to parameterize the database name, path and file name in an `SSIS` Package, how do I do that?

Details:

The script, which works, I got this by right click at Restore in Ms SQL server:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [DataSystem2014] FROM  DISK = N'F:\Folders\99_Temp\12_DataSystem\DataSystem_20140915_181216.BAK' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'DataSystem2014' TO N'F:\DatabaseFiles\DataSystem2014_Primary.mdf',  MOVE N'DataSystem2014_log' TO N'F:\DatabaseLogFiles\DataSystem2014_Primary.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO
```

but I'd like to use above as an SQL task in an `SSIS` package, and I couldn't properly parameterize the database name ( `[DataSystem2014]` ) or the path ( `F:\Folders\99_Temp\12_DataSystem\` ) or the file name ( `DataSystem_20140915_181216.BAK` ).

The database name will be fairly stable, but would like to bring it in to the SQL statement as a parameter, path might change but also stable enough, the file name always changes. I tried a few versions, used ? and parameter mapping, used `@[User::Variable]` in SQL statement, but couldn't get them working, always error messages.

Is this something I could get some help with, how to do this, please?

Comment: Actually I tried again and it works now. Not sure what was the problem, I just used 1 parameter only, and put it (the ? itself) to a new line, with blank lines above and below, and works now,t hanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

The Task for issuing SQL Statements is called the `Execute SQL Task`. Depending on your Connection Manager type, you will use different characters for placeholders.  [Map Query Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355.aspx) 
Generally speaking, people use an OLE DB connection manager when working with SQL Server so the replacement character is a `?`. That is going to be an ordinal based replacement token so even if you have the same string in there N times, you would be having to add N `?` and make N variable mappings.

Looking at your query,

```
RESTORE DATABASE 
    [DataSystem2014] 
FROM  DISK = N'F:\Folders\99_Temp\12_DataSystem\DataSystem_20140915_181216.BAK' WITH  FILE = 1
,  MOVE N'DataSystem2014' TO N'F:\DatabaseFiles\DataSystem2014_Primary.mdf'
,  MOVE N'DataSystem2014_log' TO N'F:\DatabaseLogFiles\DataSystem2014_Primary.ldf'
,  NOUNLOAD
,  STATS = 5;
```

it could be as heavily parameterized as this

```
RESTORE DATABASE 
    ?
FROM  
    DISK = ? WITH  FILE = 1
,   MOVE ? TO ?
,   MOVE ? TO ?
,   NOUNLOAD
,   STATS = 5;
```

Since those are all unique-ish values, I'd create a number of Variables within SSIS to hold their values. Actually, I'd create more Variables than I directly map.

For example, my restored database, DataSystem2014, name might always match the virtual name of the data and log so knowing one, I could derive the other values. The mechanism for deriving values is an Expression. Thus if create a Variable called `@[User::BaseDBName]`, I could then create `@[User::DBLogName]` by setting `EvaluateAsExpression = true` and then using a formula like

```
@[User::BaseDBName] + "_log"
```

You can see in the linked MSDN article how actually map these Variables to their placeholders in the query.

Where this all falls apart though, at least in my mind, is when you have multiple data files. You're now looking at building your restore command dynamically.

Comment: for the first parameter (?), can I ask you to give me the exact example, please? I still couldn't get it working

Comment: let me test again and get the exact error message, just need to switch user for that

Comment: Consider giving the person who helped you credit by a vote up and marking it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you know what you are doing with parameterized execute sql tasks and skip right to the solution I had when doing this.

declare variables in the sql with quotename('?') and then build dynamic sql to execute the restore statement.

hope it helps.

Comment: I tried quotename('?') but couldn’t get it working.

This is the error message I got:
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "USE [master]
DECLARE @FolderName nvarchar(256) = ..." failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: This is what I used in the SQL statement:
RESTORE DATABASE quotename('?') FROM  DISK = …..

this is what I used at Parameter mapping tab:
Variable name, Direction, DataType, ParameterName, ParameterSize
User::MyVariableNewDatabaseName, Input, NVARCHAR, 0, -1

And the parameter MyVariableNewDatabaseName had the value:
[DataSystem2014]

What am I doing wrong?